# mso-line-height and mso-text-raise not working in Outlook 2013?

Tags: css, outlook, html-email, outlook-2013, outlook-2011

I have a footer with 3 columns that are all strictly nested in a table-based layout for an HTML email template. I'm trying to fix the footer in which the line height for the third column does not match the top baseline of the first two.

I've been doing research to see if there was a fix for this and tried a variation of `mso-line-height-rule:exactly; mso-text-raise:44px;` to the last column where `line-height` is declared but it doesn't seem to be having any effect.

You can see in the image below, the text shifted down on the last column and text is spaced out a bit unlike the second image which renders in the email correctly.

**Outlook 2013 (in Amazon Workspace - Windows 7 Pro):**

[image: Outlook 2013]

**Outlook 2011 for Mac:**

[image]

**Footer code:**

```
            <!-- Footer -->
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">             
                <tr>
                    <td class="content-spacing" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left" width="1"></td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="mobile-shell">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="td" style="width:650px; min-width:650px; font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal; Margin:0">
                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%"><tr><td height="25" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td></tr></table>

                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <!-- Column 1 -->
                                                        <th class="column-top" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal; vertical-align:top; Margin:0" width="150">
                                                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td><div class="img" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left"><image src="https://www.designevo.com/res/templates/thumb_small/black-and-yellow-basketball.png" border="0" width="120" height="120" alt="Healthy Moms. Strong Babies." /></div></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <!-- END Column 1 -->

                                                        <!-- Column -->
                                                        <th class="column" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal; Margin:0" width="20"><div style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt;" class="mobile-br-20"></div></th>
                                                        <!-- END Column -->

                                                        <!-- Column 2 -->
                                                        <th class="column-top" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal; vertical-align:top; Margin:0" width="150">
                                                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td>       

                                                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <!-- Button -->
                                                                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td align="left">
                                                                                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="blue" style="border-radius: 0;">
                                                                                        <tr>
                                                                                            <td class="img" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left" width="18"></td>
                                                                                            <td>
                                                                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%"><tr><td height="10" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td></tr></table>

                                                                                                <div class="text-button" style="color:#ffffff; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:19px; line-height:18px; text-align:center; text-transform:uppercase">
                                                                                                    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="link-white" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none"><span class="link-white" style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bolder;">BUTTON</span></a>
                                                                                                </div>
                                                                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%"><tr><td height="10" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td></tr></table>

                                                                                            </td>
                                                                                            <td class="img" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left" width="18"></td>
                                                                                        </tr>
                                                                                    </table>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                        <!-- END Button -->

                                                                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%"><tr><td height="10" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td></tr></table>

                                                                        <div class="text-col-2" style="color:#0F1934; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:24px; text-transform:capitalize; font-weight: bolder; text-align:left;">
                                                                            <span class="purple-text">Connect With Us</span>
                                                                        </div>

                                                                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%"><tr><td height="5" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td></tr></table>

                                                                        <!-- Social Icons -->
                                                                        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td class="img" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left" width="27"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="#" src="" width="23" height="23"/></a></td>
                                                                                <td class="img" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left" width="27"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="#" src="#" width="23" height="23"/></a></td>
                                                                                <td class="img" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left" width="25"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="#" src="#" width="21" height="23"></a></td>
                                                                                <td class="img" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left" width="27"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="#" src="#" width="23" height="23"></a></td>            
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                        <!-- END Social Icons -->
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <!-- END Column 2 -->
                                                        <!-- Column -->
                                                        <th class="column" style="font-size:0pt; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal; Margin:0" width="20"><div style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt;" class="mobile-br-20"></div></th>
                                                        <!-- END Column -->
                                                        <!-- Column 3 -->
                                                        <th class="column-top" style="font-size:0pt; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal; vertical-align:top; Margin:0" width="400">
                                                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td><div class="text-col-3 copyright-text" style="color:#0F1934; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; mso-text-raise:44px; line-height:24px; text-align:left;">
                                                                            <span style="font-size:14px; color:#787985; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; mso-text-raise:44px; line-height:15px;">The Company, 1234 Main Street
                                                                            <br/>
                                                                            Suite 9999, Los Angeles, CA 10001</span>
                                                                            <br/>
                                                                            <br/>
                                                                            <span style="font-size:12px; color:#787985; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; mso-text-raise:44px; line-height:17px;">&amp;copy; 2019 The Company
                                                                            <br/>
                                                                            All Rights Reserved
                                                                            <br/>
                                                                            <a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#787985;">Terms, Privacy &amp; Notices</a></span>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </td>                
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </th>
                                                        <!-- END Column 3 -->
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%"><tr><td height="50" class="spacer" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:center; width:100%; min-width:100%">&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td class="content-spacing" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; text-align:left" width="1"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- END Footer -->
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outlook support for `div` is spotty.

Remove the `div` and move the style sheet to the parent `td`. Use `line-height` instead, so it works for all email clients.

Remove `span` and use `p` instead.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="text-col-3 copyright-text" style="color: #0F1934; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 15px; text-align: left;">
        <p>The Company, 1234 Main Street
        <br />
        Suite 9999, Los Angeles, CA 10001</p>

        <p>&amp;copy; 2019 The Company
        <br />
        All Rights Reserved
        <br />
        <a href="#" target="_blank" style="color: #787985;">Terms, Privacy &amp; Notices</a></p>
      </td>                
  </tr>
</table>
```

Good luck.

Comment: which is better using ghost table or converting all div to table structure?

Comment: As a note, there are still email clients that don't accept 2 classes in a single element for HTML email and will only apply the first one. For the greatest client compatibility, it's advisable to nest a <span> inside the <td> with the second class unless you will have block level elements inside the <td> as well